# Return column number of min value in dataframe

Tags: r, data-frame

So as a result of a bunch of preceding calculations I end up with a dataframe of varying numbers of rows and columns.

I want to find the minimum value of the df and return the row and column index. How can I do this ? For example the below data is a typical output:

```
row.names   2838        2849        2865
2768        9118.4184   14548.0008  6118.441
2769        10749.0109  18873.3781  14490.520
2775        11336.9757  19230.1397  13515.399
2780        3535.5576   11619.9425  5497.814
2842        2946.4059   10614.0673  5994.932
2843        127.0874    5250.5626   6012.107
2844        11684.4736  3851.1980   13670.723
2846        449.1957    149.3105    6171.846
2862        8574.5068   8143.8069   14397.451
```

This line will correctly give me the row index of the lowest value (127.0874):

```
    > which(df==min(df))
    [1] 6
```

But what command will return me the column index for the minimum value?

Answer (score 5):

The "index" is the position in the array and differs from the names of the rows and columns. Your solution depends on "row.names" and "names" and does not return an index. A safer way to do this (particularly on large arrays) would be:

```
( df <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10)) )

# Return min col index
  which.min(apply(df,MARGIN=2,min))

# Return min row index
  which.min(apply(df,MARGIN=1,min))
```

If you then wanted the associated column or row name you can use this index with names() or rownames().

```
# Column name with minimum value
names(df)[which.min(apply(df,MARGIN=2,min))]

# Row name with minimum value
rownames(df)[which.min(apply(df,MARGIN=1,min))]
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey - I will try that - I've found at least 2 situations where my solution breaks already!

Comment: If your data is a matrix you can either directly/indirectly coerce into a dataframe or alternatively, use row.names(), colnames(). However, it is not uncommon that the margins of matrices do not have names associated with them. Because of this, it is safer to coerce into a dataframe object class using as.data.frame() before applying a function.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out myself.

```
    min.row <- row.names(df)[(which(df==min(df)))]
    min.col <- names(which(df[min.row,]==min(df)))

    > min.row
    [1] "2843"
    > min.col
    [1] "2838"
```

But it doesn't work when there is only 1 column in dataframe and when min value is not in first column.

Comment: Forget this anyone reading - doesn't work when there is only 1 column in dataframe and doesn't work when min value is not in first column

Comment: You can use the delete button beneath your Answer if you wish to prevent anyone reading it.